# ERROR:Element type "uses-permission" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to convert web page to an app.But every time I try to run it in my device attached to laptop my usb, these errors show up.

Error:Element type "uses-permission" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

and

Error:Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\MUKESH\AndroidStudioProjects\New\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lxBs.jpg
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.garvit.anew">
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"s />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Firstnew"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Please express your code in the form of text and not as a low resolution picture.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"s />
> ```

So you have the element type: `uses-permission`

Then an attribute specification: `android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"`

And then something which is not an attribute specification: `s`

… which is an error and should be removed.